# How to give list of feature files to be executed in behave command

Tags: python-3.x, bdd, python-behave

I am having multiple folders inside the features folder, and I want to run only a specific feature file from files that resides inside these multiple folders.
So let's say there are 10 files inside features folder, 5 in *features>folder1* and 5 in *features>folder2*. I want to execute 2 feature files from folder1 and 2 feature files from folder2.

I am having a feature file name with me. Is there any way to pass it with the behave command?

I have gone through [configuration parameters](https://behave.readthedocs.io/en/latest/behave.html#docid-behave-configuration-files), but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

the path you can pass from your parent directory till the feature file

```
behave  .\features\tutorial.feature
```

**outcome:**

```
 PS C:\Arpan Saini\Automation-Projects\python\PythonBehaveBDD> behave  .\features\tutorial.feature
@regression
Feature: showing off behave # features/tutorial.feature:2

  @slow
  Scenario: run a slow test          # features/tutorial.feature:5
    Given we have behave installed   # features/steps/tutorial.py:3
    When we implement a test         # features/steps/tutorial.py:7
    Then behave will test it for us! # features/steps/tutorial.py:11

  @wip
  Scenario: run a wip test           # features/tutorial.feature:11
    Given we have behave installed   # features/steps/tutorial.py:3
    When we implement a test         # features/steps/tutorial.py:7
    Then behave will test it for us! # features/steps/tutorial.py:11

  @wip @slow
  Scenario: run a wip and slow test  # features/tutorial.feature:17
    Given we have behave installed   # features/steps/tutorial.py:3
    When we implement a test         # features/steps/tutorial.py:7
    Then behave will test it for us! # features/steps/tutorial.py:11

1 feature passed, 0 failed, 0 skipped
3 scenarios passed, 0 failed, 0 skipped
9 steps passed, 0 failed, 0 skipped, 0 undefined
Took 0m0.006s
PS C:\Arpan Saini\Automation-Projects\python\PythonBehaveBDD>
```

**For More Details please read the below documentation**

https://behave.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html#controlling-things-with-tags

**i have below question open that's not working related to tags**

[Even though have installed "cucumber-tag-expressions 3.0.0" the behave command with "and" and "or" operator are not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64301555/even-though-have-installed-cucumber-tag-expressions-3-0-0-the-behave-command-w)