# Even though have installed "cucumber-tag-expressions 3.0.0" the behave command with "and" and "or" operator are not working

Tags: python-behave

Resources:

**Repository:**
https://github.com/anton-lin/tag-expressions-python

**Behave Documentation for tags:**
https://behave.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tag_expressions.html

**package name:** :
https://pypi.org/project/cucumber-tag-expressions/

My Feature File

```
@regression
Feature: showing off behave

  @slow
  Scenario: run a slow test
    Given we have behave installed
    When we implement a test
    Then behave will test it for us!

  @wip
  Scenario: run a wip test
    Given we have behave installed
    When we implement a test
    Then behave will test it for us!

  @wip @slow
  Scenario: run a wip and slow test
    Given we have behave installed
    When we implement a test
    Then behave will test it for us!
```

Tried commands none of them working: getting results zero scenarios are run

```
behave --tags="not @slow" .\features\tutorial.feature
behave --tags="@slow and @wip" .\features\tutorial.feature
behave --tags="@slow or @wip" .\features\tutorial.feature
```

**While command with single tag is working fine and executing only scenarios of that specific tag**

**Getting Below outcome with all three commands:**

```
@regression
Feature: showing off behave # features/tutorial.feature:2

  @slow
  Scenario: run a slow test          # features/tutorial.feature:5
    Given we have behave installed   # None
    When we implement a test         # None
    Then behave will test it for us! # None

  @wip
  Scenario: run a wip test           # features/tutorial.feature:11
    Given we have behave installed   # None
    When we implement a test         # None
    Then behave will test it for us! # None

  @wip @slow
  Scenario: run a wip and slow test  # features/tutorial.feature:17
    Given we have behave installed   # None
    When we implement a test         # None
    Then behave will test it for us! # None

0 features passed, 0 failed, 1 skipped
0 scenarios passed, 0 failed, 3 skipped
0 steps passed, 0 failed, 9 skipped, 0 undefined
Took 0m0.000s
```

Comment: Which version of `behave` do you have installed on your system?

Comment: i have got behave 1.2.6 installed.

Answer (score 2):

'and'/'or' usage as you have attempted is not available in `python-behave 1.2.6`.

For **1.2.6** try instead:

**OR example:**

```
behave --tags @slow,@wip
```

**AND example:**

```
behave --tags @slow, --tags @wip
```

**Negative tag example:**

```
behave --tags ~@slow
```

See further docs with

```
behave --tags-help
```

The reason for the confusion is that when you install `behave`, by default you pull the most recent **stable** version from places like [pypi.org](https://pypi.org/project/behave/) (so 1.2.6), while the `behave` docs refer to the "latest" version (1.2.7, which has been in development for quite some time now).
The same issue was raised and closed a while ago in [github and closed](https://github.com/behave/behave/issues/763).

Comment: Thank you Obuz for the explination. I found the same instruction in behave 1.2.6  library code and it worked.